# Excel apply border to active cell row range?

Tags: excel, vba, border

I am trying to apply a border from range A to Range M on the active cell row by using the following.

```
Range("A:" & ActiveCell.Row & "M" & ActiveCell.Row).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

For some reason this doesn't work, pleas can someone show me where i am going worng?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems.

First, your colon is in the wrong spot. Eg:

```
Range("A:" & ActiveCell.Row & "M" & ActiveCell.Row).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

should be:

```
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":M" & ActiveCell.Row).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Second, xlInsideHorizontal puts borders *inside* the range, but you are selecting a range that has no inside borders.

Imagine that your active row is 10. Your code is saying:

```
Range("A10:M10").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Range A10 to M10 has no inside cells to apply an inside border to.